# fprintd: The driver encountered a protocol error with the device

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, authentication, device-tree, fingerprint

I am trying to make work my finger print sensor thinkpad x390 yoga. I installed `printfd` package using yay. When I try to run `fprintd-enroll`, I get this error:

```
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
failed to claim device: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.Internal: Open failed with error: The driver encountered a protocol error with the device.
```

When I try to run it for second time I get this:

```
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
failed to claim device: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.Internal: Open failed with error: Device 06cb:00bd is already open
```

I tried installing `thinkfinger` package but stillno luck. How can I resolve this problem ?

This is my `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. Prometheus MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04f2:b67c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 033: ID 2cb7:0210 Fibocom L830-EB-00 LTE WWAN Modem
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 056a:51af Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Please check if there is a newer firmware using [fwupdmgr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fwupd), maybe you also need to update `fprintd`, 
see [gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/181#note_557794](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/181#note_557794).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to update firmware of fingerprint device. I achieved by:

1. Installing fwupd

```
sudo pacman -S fwupd
```

2. Check if system can see device:

```
fwupdmgr get-devices
```

3. Refresh firmware database:

```
fwupdmgr refresh --force
```

4. Updating my firmware:

```
fwupdmgr update
```

You have to reboot immediatlly to apply update and prevent your device from weird behavior.

---

After all these steps `fprintd-enroll` will run without problems

Comment: not in my case - here I still face problem that device is open by some other process

Comment: @silpol For that have a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/878072/lenovo-finger-print-reader-already-claimed